# Curve family whose velocities are normalized exponentials

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, exponential-function

For a fixed $\gamma > 0$, consider the family of curves parametrized by $\Theta=(\vec a,\vec b)$:

$$\vec v_\Theta(t) = \frac{\vec a + e^{\gamma t}\vec b}{||\vec a + e^{\gamma t}\vec b||_2}$$

I'm interested in their integrals

$$\vec x_\Theta(t) = \int_0^t \vec v(t')\,dt'$$
$$\vec w_\Theta(t) = \int_0^t e^{\gamma t'}\vec v(t')\,dt'$$

I don't need $\vec x_\Theta(t)$ and $\vec w_\Theta(t)$ as functions of $\Theta=(\vec a,\vec b)$. Rather, I'd like to know if there's a nice form for a general element of the set

$$\{\vec x_\Theta(\cdot): \Theta\in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n\}$$

and similarly for $\vec w_\Theta(\cdot)$. For example, an answer might take the form of another parametric family, parametrized by $\Theta$ or by something more convenient. I suppose there is no loss of generality in assuming we're in two dimensions (spanned by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$), in which case we can say that $\vec v$ is a unit vector whose direction satisfies

$$\tan\theta(t)
= \frac{a_y + e^{\gamma t}b_y}{a_x + e^{\gamma t}b_x}$$

Are these well-known types of curves? At the very minimum, is there a faster and higher-precision way to compute the curves than numerical integration?

Comment: Not sure that this would help, but very fast $\vec v(t)$ becomes $\hat b$

Comment: @Andrei it does but I'm also interested in the answer for smaller $t$ and to a high degree of precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project $\vec x$ into directions along $\hat a$ and $\hat b$. Then $$x_a(t)-x_a(0)=\int_0^t\frac 1{\sqrt{a^2+b^2e^{2\lambda t'}}}dt'$$
If either $a$ or $b$ are zero, the integral is trivial. If both are nonzero, use $c=b/a$ and $-2\lambda t'=\tau$ to get an integral $$\int\frac1{\sqrt{1+c^2e^{-\tau}}}d\tau$$
Now use $u=1+c^2e^{-\tau}$ to get an integral of the form $$\int\frac1{(u-1)\sqrt u}du$$
Substitute $v=\sqrt u$ and you get $$\int\frac1{v^2-1}dv$$
You will need to get all the constants and the limits. The last integral is trivial.
Similarly for the other direction:
$$x_b(t)-x_b(0)=\int_0^t\frac {be^{\lambda t'}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2e^{2\lambda t'}}}dt'$$
Use $u=\frac bae^{\lambda t'}$ to get an integral of the form $$\int\frac1{\sqrt{1+u^2}}du$$
This is a standard integral

Comment: Thanks! Your denominator needs adjustment if $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are not orthogonal, but I finally got it with your help and Wolfram Alpha. WLOG let $\vec a = \hat a + a \hat b,\; \vec b = b\hat b$ where $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ are orthonormal. For all of the integrals, the key substitution to make is $u=a + be^{\gamma t}$.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that.

Comment: Oh hey, one difficulty. We end up with this mess:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+du%2F%28%28u-a%29sqrt%281%2Bu%5E2%29%29
Luckily, both limits of integration are on the same side of $a$, but they could be on either side, so the Wolfram expression can't be right in general. Is it correct if we just replace $\ln(a-u)$ with $\ln|a-u|$?

Comment: Then it does not matter. You will get a logarithm of a ratio, so the sign will cancel